# How do I make Visual Studio Start Page display my checked out files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe, report, start-page

We use Visual Source Safe. Is there a way to have the all-files-checked-out-to-me report display on the Start Page in Visual Studio? So that when I opened VS, I'd see a report of everything I have checked out from VSS, categorized by project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a more complicated approach than you're interested in, but since the start page can show RSS feeds, you could write a web app that would query VSS via the COM interface, list your checkouts, and publish that as a feed.

If you're not looking to roll your own, I did a quick search and came across [VssRssSvc](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2004/11/22/rss-and-sourcesafe-2/), an application that generates RSS feeds from a VSS database. It includes source, so you'd be pretty close to getting what you're after with a little bit of work.

If you decide to build it, let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks - yeah, looks like he's done most of the work for me. Pretty much dead on what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2010 allows customization of the start page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vs2010ctpeditor/thread/0c8d5c13-7f4a-4b11-934b-7a0b65da095b), altough I don't know if this could solve your problem.

Comment: Just looked that over, looks pretty awesome. You can point the start page to a WPF/XAML application. :O

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to customize the Start Page.  You should be able to see all your checked-out (and modified) files in the Pending Changes window.  Beyond that you'd probably have to customize VS with an Addin or Package.